# Sorting tuples by randomly generated weight

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

**The problem:**
I have a list of tuples containing a string and an int. I have managed sorting the tuples by their second value using the built in sorted function and lambda. The problem with that is that I also need to group up the tuples in case they have the same int. After they are sorted in groups I need to generate a random number between 1 and 6 and based on the highest put the corresponding tuple inside a final list which is meant to represent the truly sorted tuples.

**Context:** The algorithm is meant to be an Initiative roller for a roleplay game and comparing one value to the next does not suffice, all tuples that have the same int value need to be compared at the same time and not one after another.

**Current code:**

```
iniList = [('Enemy 3', 15), ('Aldare', 14), ('Enemy 2', 14), ('Enemy 5', 14), ('Enemy 1', 13), ('Enemy 4', 13)]
finalIniList = [] #the list meant to contain the tuples when they are sorted
iniGroups = []
    currentIni = iniList[0][1]
    currentIniGroup = []
    finalIniList = []
    for x in range(len(iniList)):
        if(currentIni == iniList[x][1]):
            currentIniGroup.append(iniList[x])
            if(x == len(iniList) - 1): iniGroups.append(currentIniGroup)
        else:
            iniGroups.append(currentIniGroup)
            currentIniGroup = []
            currentIniGroup.append(iniList[x])
            currentIni = iniList[x][1]
            if(x == len(iniList) - 1): iniGroups.append(currentIniGroup)
for item in iniGroups:
        print(item)
```

**Output:**

```
[('Enemy 3', 15)]
[('Aldare', 14), ('Enemy 2', 14), ('Enemy 5', 14)]
[('Enemy 1', 13), ('Enemy 4', 13)]
```

Comment: You can use ```itertools.groupby``` to generate the sub-groups

Comment: Are you willing/able to reconsider data structure? Perhaps a sorted dictionary of initiative rolls? e.g. `{15: ['Enemy 3'], 14: ['Aldare','Enemy 2','Enemy 5'], 13: ['Enemy 1','Enemy 4']}` might be easier to process?

Comment: @Homer512 I already saw that that's possible but I found it only after I already completed my current algorithm and since it works I left it be.

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp I could definitely do that though I don't see how that would make it any easier so if possible please elaborate on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given

```py
iniList = [('Enemy 3', 15), ('Aldare', 14), ('Enemy 2', 14), ('Enemy 5', 14), ('Enemy 1', 13), ('Enemy 4', 13)]
```

use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle):

```py
from random import sample
from itertools import groupby

finalIniList = [(group[0],
                 sample(list_:=[tup[0] for tup in group[1]],k=len(list_)),
                )
                for group in groupby(iniList,key=lambda tup: tup[1])
               ]
```

to get something like

```py
>>> finalIniList
[
 (highest_initiative, ['shuffled', 'list', 'of', 'entities']),
 (lower_initiative,   ['entity']),
 (lowest_initiative,  ['some', 'more', 'entities', 'randomly', 'ordered']),
]
```

Comment: I just tested it out and it does indeed take care of sorting them into groups it still does not take care of the actual problem which is to sort the things inside the groups based on a random value between 1 and 6.

Comment: sorry that one didnt post as i wrote the comment let me test it out

Comment: `finalIniList = [(g[0],sample(x:=[i[0] for i in list(map(list, g[1]))],k=len(x))) for g in groupby(iniList,key=lambda i: i[1])]` took care of everything, thanks a lot!

Comment: @PandSkin is the "between 1 and 6" a necessary component of your needed answer? In all honesty, this answer just randomly orders your entities/characters if they have the same initiative.

Comment: I just commented on the answer down below, its not a necessary element, its just a way for humans to do it when playing but the end goal is to randomize it in case people have the same ini so as long as that is achieved and done at the same time the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

> After they are sorted in groups I need to generate a random number between 1 and 6 and based on the highest put the corresponding tuple inside a final list which is meant to represent the truly sorted tuples.

And how do you break ties if that randomly generated number is the same for two items?

If you're satisfied with simply randomly uniformly sorting within the groups, you could do the following:

```py
import random

def sort_with_grouping(ll):
    n = len(ll)
    idx_list = list(range(n))
    random.shuffle(idx_list)
    ll_with_idx = [(s, i, i*n + idx)for (s, i), idx in zip(ll, idx_list)]
    ll_with_idx.sort(key=lambda t: -t[2])
    
    return [(s, i) for (s, i, _) in ll_with_idx]
```

This works provided the square of the length of your list if smaller than the maximum integer, which I doubt will be a problem. You can seed the random number generator if you wish.

Comment: The breaking ties was the problem in fact. I'm more than happy with just randomly shuffling the values inside the iniList and the answer I marked as solution, if I'm not mistaken does exactly that. The target is randomizing the values in case they are the same the 1 to 6 roll is the way its solved in the rulebook of the roleplay game but it achieves the same thing as simply randomizing the values at the same time.